# Gitlab getting artifact from pre merge to post merge job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am running a job pre merge with condition

```
rules:
  if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```

in the job a file is generated which I have added as artifact.
Is there any way to make this file available in a post merge separate job.